# using x2y2 axes in a heatmap with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap, axis-labels

Creating a heatmap with gnuplot, I want to have the tic labels read from the datafile on top and right of the heatmap, but setting `axes x2y2` doesn't work as expected.

Example data file:

```
.   sample1 sample2 sample3
gene1   10  0   17
gene2   11  2   21
gene3   9   27  0
```

Using

`plot "data.csv" matrix rowheaders columnheaders with image`

I get this plot, which is fine:

[image]

However, if I want to have the tic labels on the x2 and y2 axes, using i.e.

```
unset xtics
unset ytics
set x2tics
set y2tics
plot "data.csv" matrix rowheaders columnheaders using 1:2:3 axes x2y2 with image
```

gnuplot uses numbers instead of my labels:

[image]

Is there a way to attach the tic labels read from the file to the x2 and y2 axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `x2label` and `y2label`:

```
set x2label "Some label"
set y2label "Some other label"
plot sin(x) notitle axes x2y2
```

gives

[image]

If you also want to move the tic marks to the upper and right side, then you have to enable them for the `x2` and `y2` axes and disable them for `x` and `y`:

```
set x2label "Some label"
set y2label "Some other label"
unset xtics
unset ytics
set x2tics
set y2tics
plot sin(x) notitle axes x2y2
```

gives

[image]

## Update

Thanks for editing the question. It looks like your main question is whether you can use the labels read from the data file for the `x2label` and `y2label`. I am not sure if that is possible; it seems that the `rowheaders` and `columnheaders` options always refer to the first coordinate system.

As a workaround you can stick to `xlabel`/`ylabel`, and move them to the other side of the graph. This might require playing with the margins a little:

```
set tmargin 2
set lmargin 0.5
set rmargin at screen 0.75
set colorbox user origin screen 0.88, graph 0 size screen 0.05, graph 1

set xtics offset 0, graph 1.07
set ytics offset graph 1.15, 0

plot "data.csv" matrix rowheaders columnheaders  with image
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working with heatmaps. I improved my question to make it more clear.